# FFMPEG Multiple task for converting video to image sequence for MacOS

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, task, sequence

I need help to make multiple task of that on MacOS:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -r 0.1 output_%04d.jpg
```

I have basically 200 video files to do that action and I want to create a single code that I can send to ffmpeg at once. I have tried with & in the end but it didn't work.

please help!
Gabriel

Comment: It's a MacOS. thank you!

Comment: See answer in [FFMPEG Multiple task for converting video to image sequence for MacOS](https://superuser.com/a/1588780/). Also, crossposting should be avoided.